# How to display a video in a CardView on Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-cardview

I'm fairly new to Android and I recently added a `CardView` to my app to display a few text boxes and images, which work just fine.

However, when I tried to display a video the card remains empty. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

I've defined the `ImageView` like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <VideoView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/step1Vid" />
                        <MediaController
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/mediaController2"
                            android:layout_below="@id/step1Vid" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/step_image"/>
               </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

initially i tried to set the video in the onCreate of the relevant Activity like so:

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.step1Vid);
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(SOME_MP4_URL);
    video.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    MediaController mCon = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
    mCon.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mCon);
```

That didn't work not sure why. so Then from the relevant `Activity` I used `AsyncTask` to get a video from a URL. used the same code inside the onProgressMethod because of the UI changes which didn't work either.

I would appreciate any advice I can get.

Comment: Please provide your asynctask code

Comment: show the related code, not just the layout

Answer (score 1):

problem was solved when i gave the LinearLayout a fixed size instead of using the "wrap_content" attribute.